# wsadmin: wsInstallApp ejb reference mapping error

Tags: websphere, ear, wsadmin, automated-deployment

I am trying to install EAR file with EJB module on IBM WAS 7.0.0.27 by using WSADMIN-wsInstallApp (for automation). but its getting below error

```
**WASX7109E: Insufficient data for install task "MapResRefToEJB.**
```

But the same ear file can be deployed manually by IBM console.

it looks ejb mapping reference issue. i tried so many ways but couldnt get the solution.

can anyone please suggest for a solution.

Code

```
target name="installEAR"
   wsInstallApp ear="${earFile}" options="-appname ${application}"    wasHome="${wasHome.dir}" profileName="${profileName}" conntype="${connType}" port="${port}" host="${hostName}" user="${userId}" password="${password}" /target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
options="app-name ${application} -usedefaultbindings"
```

If you actually want to specify bindings, you'll need to replace `-usedefaultbindings` with `-MapResRefToEJB ...`, where the options you specify need to be formatted based on the wsadmin scripting language you're using (jacl or jython).  See the InfoCenter for a full [AdminApp options](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html), including `-MapResRefToEJB` and `-MapModulesToServers`.

Comment: it Works. :) Thanks bkail. one more issue raises after wsIntstallApp.
script executes in the following 
1. List application
2. Stop Application
3. Uninstall Application
4. save changes $AdminConfig save
5. Install ear
6. save changes- $AdminConfig save
7. Start Application
All first 5 the steps are successful, exception is thrown in step 7
com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Application not installed

Comment: Are you running in an ND environment (dmgr, nodeagent, server)?  If yes, then you need a nodesync.  Otherwise, I don't know why that error would occur, sorry.

Comment: yes set node sync option. and its working. but startApp is not consistent. after installing ear sometimes its getting started and sometimes it saying application not installed even its installed successfully. i also used AdminConfig save and isAppreadyOption. Thanks kbail.

Comment: I have seen problems with isAppReady being insufficient in my own testing, and so my automation uses a hardcoded 10s sleep.  If that solution isn't suitable for you, I suggest opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Great. Thanks @bkail. i have set time delay in seconds and the ear application started successfully. <sleep seconds="10"/>.am working with multiple ear build and deployment automation. how can i map webmodules to webserver/app server using wsadmin install options. currently its showing web module maps to webserver in manage modules link and the application start status is unknown.

Comment: This is getting away from the original question; you should probably accept the answer and open a new question.  That said, you need to use the `-MapModulesToServers` option.  I've updated the answer slightly to mention that documentation for that option is on the same AdminApp options InfoCenter page.

Comment: If an answer helps you, you're encouraged to click the checkmark to the left of the answer (if you asked the question), or to click the up arrow (if you found an answer to a question asked by someone else).